# Is it possible to pull multiple subarrays from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Take the following. I can pull record matching "1967" for `_id = 1` by doing the following. Is it possible to print awards that match 1967 and school name matching "Penn?"

```
db.bios.find({_id:1, "awards.year" : 1967},{"awards.$":1}).pretty()


db.bios.insert(
    {
        _id: 1,
        awards: [
            {
                award: 'W.W. McDowell Award',
                year: 1967,
                by: 'IEEE Computer Society'
            },
            {
                award: 'National Medal of Science',
                year: 1975,
                by: 'National Science Foundation'
            },
         ],
         "schools" : [
             {
                name : "Harvard",
                year : 1945
             },
             {
                name : "Penn",
                year : 1950
             }
         ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of v2.2.2 you can only use one `$` positional operator per query, but you can use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator multiple times to do this:

```js
db.bios.find({_id:1}, {
    awards: {$elemMatch: {year: 1967}}, 
    schools: {$elemMatch: {name: "Penn"}}
}).pretty()
```

outputs:

```js
{
  "_id": 1,
  "awards": [
    {
      "award": "W.W. McDowell Award",
      "year": 1967,
      "by": "IEEE Computer Society"
    }
  ],
  "schools": [
    {
      "name": "Penn",
      "year": 1950
    }
  ]
}
```